# Is using shorthand quick substitution of history expansion problematic?

Tags: bash, command-history, history-expansion

In my terminal (bash 3), I sometimes use the quick substitution

```
^aa^bb^
```

> `^string1^string2^`
>
> ```
>          Quick substitution.  Repeat the last command, replacing string1 with string2.  Equivalent to `!!:s/string1/string2/` (see Modifiers below).
> ```

For example

```
$ echo aa aa
aa aa
$ ^aa^bb^
echo bb aa
bb aa
```

Which is really handy in some cases.

However, I found out that omitting the last `^` also works, i.e.

```
$ echo aa aa
aa aa
$ ^aa^bb
echo bb aa
bb aa
```

My question is: what is the consequence of omitting the closing `^`? Can I safely leave it out or are there any caveats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be omitted if it is the last character of the event line.

First, we check what `^string1^string2^` meaning from `man bash`:

```
^string1^string2^
              Quick  substitution.   Repeat   the   previous   command,   
              replacing   string1   with   string2.    Equivalent   to
              ``!!:s/string1/string2/'' (see Modifiers below).
```

So it's equivalent to `s/string1/string2/`. Read documentation of `s` modifier:

```
s/old/new/
          Substitute new for the first occurrence of old in the event line.  
          Any delimiter can be used in  place  of  /. The final  delimiter  
          is optional if it is the last character of the event line. The 
          delimiter may be quoted in old and new with a single backslash.  
          If & appears in new, it is replaced by old.  A single backslash 
          will quote the &. If old  is  null,  it is set to the last old 
          substituted, or, if no previous history substitutions took place, 
          the last string in a !?string[?]  search.
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Was typing long command, but your edit makes it obsolete, so I can do something like `^aa^bb^ cc`, that is interesting.